# Count the number of times a value is used

Tags: views, database

I have a situation where I have five columns in an external database I am accessing using the Views database connector module. Each column in the table contains a value between 1 and 5.

I need to count the number of times each value is used in all those five columns.

For example, the database contains these values.

```
c|c|c|c|c  
0|1|1|2|4  
1|2|4|1|5
```

The output I want is:

- For the value 1, 4
- For 2, 2
- For 3, 0
- For 4, 2
- For 5, 1

Is it possible to do this directly through the Views module, or do I need an additional module? Can I do it using custom code?